# Flushing Rails template output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, templates, flush, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm finding Rails waits until the entire view has been calculated on the server before it initiates the response and dumps everything at once. Ideally the page should be populated incrementally as the server is working.

To check this, I made a fresh Rails (4.1) project, generated a dummy resource, and added <% sleep 10 %> in the middle of its view template. The result was that *nothing* was output for 10 seconds - Chrome's network panel just shows waiting with zero bytes received. Maybe it's because it's WEBrick running in development mode, but I'm seeing similar thing with Unicorn (in dev and production).

So my question is how to ensure content is incrementally flushed in Rails. Ideally it should happen automatically ([this post implies that's the intention](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/09/07/automatic-flushing-the-rails-3-1-plan/) back in Rails 3.1), but in this simple example, there's no _content_for_) but if necessary, I'd be willing to add some flush() calls or whatever.

Comment: Is [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html) what you are looking for? (using `render stream: true`)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. I'd previously assumed streaming was just for long-running responses (ie `live`). Can you add this as an answer please and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, this was added in Rails, but not as a default: you need to trigger this behaviour by specifying the `stream` option to `render`:

```
render stream: true
```

The documentation for this feature can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html).